# Imageview to InputStream

Tags: android, kotlin

I need help trying to convert an imageView's image to be sent to a OutPutFile but needs to be read in before being sent.

This code is using a static image. Instead of this, I want to use the imageView to be the picture I send.

```
        val imageFileName: String = globals.sampN.toString() + "-" + globals.dayNo.toString() + "-" + globals.pictureCount.toString() + ".jpg"
        val storageDir: File = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        if(!storageDir.exists()) storageDir.mkdirs()

        val imageFile = File(storageDir, imageFileName)


        val myOutput:OutputStream = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        val myInput = getAssets().open("NoPhoto.jpg") // <- This is the place where it needs
        var length: Int = myInput.read(buffer)        // to be replaced with imageView
        while (length > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length)
            length = myInput.read(buffer)
        }
        myInput.close()
        myOutput.flush()
        myOutput.close()
        mailBitmap = setScaledBitmap(imageFile.absolutePath)
        println("mailBitmap " + mailBitmap.toString())
```

so far I have gotten the Bitmap to work with this string of code but I'm still stuck on the part where it sends the image file to somewhere meaningful

```
        val imageFileName: String = globals.sampN.toString() + "-" + globals.dayNo.toString() + "-" + globals.pictureCount.toString() + ".jpg"
        val storageDir: File = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        if(!storageDir.exists()) storageDir.mkdirs()

        photoImageView.buildDrawingCache()
        val imageFile = File(storageDir, imageFileName)


        val myOutput:OutputStream = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
       /* val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        val myInput = photoImageView.getDrawable() as Bitmap
        var length: Int = myInput.read(buffer)
        while (length > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length)
            length = myInput.read(buffer)
        }
        myInput.close()
        myOutput.flush()
        myOutput.close()*/
        mailBitmap = photoImageView.getDrawingCache()
        println("mailBitmap " + mailBitmap.toString())
```

Comment: `ImageView.getDrawable()` should return a `BitmapDrawable` from which a `Bitmap` can be retrieved.

Comment: sadly I've tried that but i keep getting an "unresolved reference" for both read and close for the InputStream.

Comment: Why do you need an `InputStream` for writing? Your question is a bit hard to understand. What do you want to read?

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I just want to write this imageView's image to a File. Then send that File to a sever with the "myOutput.flush()"

Comment: If you have `Bitmap` and an open `OutputStream` there is `Bitmap.compress()` to write the file.

Comment: Thats what i was working with for a while but i have having really bad quality issues. Either way thanks a bunch for the help my man.